# Realm Swift 3.1.1 (Latest) cannot extend Object class

Tags: ios, swift, realm

So to make things clear first, this is not my first time importing RealmSwift into my project.

I created totally new project and add 'RealmSwift' pod into the project

then I import RealmSwift

```
import RealmSwift

class TestObject: Object { // the Object is not being suggested by the autocomplete 

    let dog = List<Dog>() // the List also not being suggested by the autocomplete
}
```

Above codes do not give compiler error. But because of this I have another problem.

I need to call my List object and then call the property.

When I tried to call the list object property from another ViewController, the suggested data type of the list property is <<\error type>>. I don't know what to do because i really need to access the property but I can't. And now my compiler gives me error.

Is there something wrong? It has never happened to me in my previous projects, just this once. Can someone help me?

I have checked the new project, there is no one calling or creating the List<> function.

Comment: anyway why you need an empty list of dogs as constant?

Comment: check if you have Dog class defined?